# How can I change the cursor of the mouse on reload of my angular application?

Tags: angular, reload

I have to reload a page in my angular application in order to reset all my data.

But when I do `window.location.reload()` I have a white screen, the user can think the application crash. So I wanted to have `cursor:wait` but it doesn't work.

**.ts file :**

```
ngOnInit() {
    document.body.style.cursor = "wait";
}
ngAfterViewInit() {
    document.body.style.cursor = "initial";
}
```

Someone have any solution ?

Comment: "I wanted to have cursor:wait but it doesn't work." -> what have you tried and what went wrong? Any error? Unexpected behaviour?

Comment: I edit my code and no I have no error or something

Comment: Maybe it is too quick for you to see it? `ngOnInit` is not launched when the application is loading, but when the component has finished initializing. Maybe in your case there's a too short time between it and `ngAfterViewInit`. Why not set the cursor as `wait` by default in your body style so that it's there right from the start, and restore initial at `ngAfterViewInit`?

Comment: So what do you mean by reset the data? There may be better ways to reset the data in Angular than using windows.location.reload(). If you can tell more about your use case may be it can be solved in Angular way.

Comment: I try but it doesn't work also.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure it is ideal to reload the whole application. You can just reload the component to update the component and the view.

```
constructor(private route : ActivatedRoute,
      private router : Router) {}

    buttonClick() {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('your_path');
    }
```

Hope this help!

Comment: First I wanted to do that but the problem is all data which have been set need to be reset.

Comment: where do you storing data?

Comment: The data are in a service and 2 .ts file.